# Tkinter canvas and items that can use Matplotlib Toolbar?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I have written a small GUI program with Tkinter because I like the ability to queue updates to the mainloop for successive item updates in order to create an interative animation of changing circle colors that are induced by data changes.

( this is something I have found matplotib to not play nicely with, i.e. if I use patches and I want to update the color of the patch I have found that I have to add a new patch on top of the existing patch, which leaves color residue)

However, I would like to benefit from Matplotlib's Toolbar so that I can use the zoom and panning functionality.

I am experimenting on how to do this with a small test program for simplicity and have gotten matplotlib and tkinter in the same window... BUT the zoom doesnt work!

I have 2 weeks experience with Matplotlib and a couple days with Tkinter so please correct me on any inaccurate statements or add additional suggestions.

Here is the small program I have written for testing in which the matplotlib zoom doesn't work:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import sys
from Tkinter import *
import matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg as tkagg




class App:

    def __init__(self, master):

        self.frame = Frame(master, bg='#FFFFFF', height=1000, width=1000,
                           borderwidth=1, relief=RAISED)
        self.frame.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)

        self.button = Button(
            self.frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=self.frame.quit
            )
        self.button.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        self.hi_there = Button(self.frame, text="Hello", command=self.say_hi)
        self.hi_there.pack(side=BOTTOM)

        ###
        # Creating a canvas for Tk items
        self.tkcanvas = Canvas(self.frame, height=600, width=600)
        self.tkcanvas.config(background='yellow')
        self.tkcanvas.pack()
        self.tkcanvas.create_rectangle(0,0,100,100,fill='blue')

        # Hoping to utilize the mpl toolbar for zooming function by doing:
        self.fig = Figure(figsize=(4,.5))
        self.mplcanvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.fig, master=self.frame)
        self.mplcanvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side='bottom', fill='both')
        self.mplcanvas._tkcanvas.pack(side='bottom', fill='both', expand=1)

        #
        self.mpltoolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( self.mplcanvas, master )
        self.mpltoolbar.update()
        self.mpltoolbar.pack()
        ###


    def say_hi(self):
        print "hi there, everyone!"

root = Tk()

app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
root.destroy()
```

Comment: FYI, there are several methods for changing the color of a matplotlib patch. (eg. set_facecolor, set_edgecolor). Type help('matplotlib.patches.Circle') at the python prompt.